# error when passing a date to where clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So this is odd and hopefully there is a simple answer. I have a SQL query that used a date as the first parameter in a where() clause. But for some reason CodeIginter appears to be trying to add in extra escape characters,

Here is my code

```
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from("equip_reserve");
        $this->db->where('equip_list_id = '.$equip_list_id);
        $this->db->where('"'. date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($startdate)) .'" between date and returndate');
```

Here is the result:

```
SELECT * FROM 'equip_reserve' WHERE 'equip_list_id' = 5 AND "2016-02-29 '14:20'" between 'date' and 'returndate'
```

As you can see the date after the AND clause is causing this statement to fail.

Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: Query parameters solve problem like these.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by just passing the SQL directly to CodeIgniter instead of using their helper functions. In case anyone ever has this problem.

```
$st = date("Y-m-d H:i",strtotime($startdate));
$sql  =  "SELECT * FROM `equip_reserve` WHERE  ? between `date` AND `returndate` and `equip_list_id` = ?"; 

$query = $this->db->query(
   $sql, 
   array($star,$equip_list_id)
```

);

return $query->result();

Fixed!